# Laravel 5 Extending core class

Tags: php, class, laravel, extend

I'm trying to extend Laravel 5 core class. What i want to achieve is that i can have custom url generators eg. URL::test(), will generate custom link.

So far i have:

1. Created app/Acme/lib folder
2. Added app/Acme/lib path to composer.json classmap

   ```
   "autoload": {
       "classmap": [
           ....
           app/Acme/lib
        ]
   }
   ```
3. Created custom UrlGenerator class in Acme/lib/CustomUrlGenerator.php

   ```
   <?php namespace App\Acme\lib;
   use \Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator;
   class CustomUrlGenerator extends UrlGenerator {
       public function test() {
          return $this->to('/test');
       }
   }
   ```
4. Created service provider app/Acme/lib/CustomUrlServiceProvider.php

   ```
   <?php namespace App\Acme\lib;
   use \Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider;
   class CustomUrlServiceProvider extends RoutingServiceProvider {
       public function boot() {
           App::bind('url', function() {
               return new CustomUrlGenerator(
                   App::make('router')->getRoutes(),
                   App::make('request')
               );
           });
           parent::boot();
       }
   }
   ```
5. Registered service provider in app/config/app.php
6. Run composer dump-autoload

Now when i run {!! URL::test() !!}, im getting 404 for every route

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
NotFoundHttpException in /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php line 143:
```

Is there something that i'm missing?
Many thanks for any help ..

Answer (score 0):

You talk about a mistake in the `RouteCollection.php` file, but you don't include it in your question. Furthermore, I would have written differently in the `composer.json`, like this:

```
"autoload": {
"classmap": [
        // ....
        "App\\Your_Namespace\\" : "app/Acme/lib",
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yep, i have fixed that (many thanks) + fixed custom service provider according to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20520861/4437438 and now it works properly

Comment: Delight to have helped